# RAID0 worse that write speeds of hard drives independently

Tags: raid, mount, mdadm, ntfs, write

So I have two hard drives one connect with SATA and one with USB3.0

> SATA (/dev/sdc1):
>       Apple HDD Toshiba
>  USB (/dev/sde2):
>       Western Digital Technologies, Inc. Elements SE Portable

mounted to `/mount1` and `/mount2` consecutively.

---

## Initial tests

I ran **write** tests using the command:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=testfileR bs=100k count=10000
```

and **read** tests using the command:

```
dd if=testfileR of=/dev/null
```

### /dev/sde2 (/mount1)

> **write:** 1024000000 bytes (1.0 GB) copied, 11.5802 s, 88.4 MB/s
>   **read:** 1024000000 bytes (1.0 GB) copied, 1.36778 s, 749 MB/s

### /dev/sdc1 (/mount2)

> **write:** 1024000000 bytes (1.0 GB) copied, 11.2735 s, 90.8 MB/s
>   **read:** 1024000000 bytes (1.0 GB) copied, 1.32109 s, 775 MB/s

---

## Creating the RAID

Now I am going to create the RAID

```
mdadm --create /dev/md1 --chunk=256 --level=0 --raid-devices=2 /dev/sdc1 /dev/sde2
```

Partion:

```
mkfs.ntfs /dev/md1 -f
```

---

## RAID test:

### /dev/md1 (/RAID2)

> **write:** 1024000000 bytes (1.0 GB) copied, 11.6064 s, 88.2 MB/s
>   **read:** 1024000000 bytes (1.0 GB) copied, 1.3568 s, 755 MB/s

---

## Conclusion

Why has the RAID not changed the write speeds?! Am I doing anything wrong?

---

#### Strange `blkid`

```
/dev/sdc1: UUID="eea8d28a-ad9a-4392-d70a-738c35a9d132" UUID_SUB="dd7d7db3-8c01-9ee6-3808-8d3a3b7dc7d1" LABEL="max-MS-7865:1" TYPE="linux_raid_member" " 
/dev/sde2: UUID="1A6318686F2C1E46" TYPE="ntfs"
```

Why is `/dev/sde2` not formatted the same as `/dev/sdc1` with `TYPE="linux_raid_member"`?

---

#### Output of `cat /proc/mdstat`

```
Personalities : [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid1] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10] 
md1 : active raid0 sde2[1] sdc1[0]
      976563968 blocks super 1.2 256k chunks

md0 : active raid0 sdb1[1] sda1[0]
      3907028992 blocks super 1.2 256k chunks

unused devices: <none>
```

Comment: Reading from `/dev/urandom` is slower than writing to your disk(s); confirm that `dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/null` still takes as long, then use `if=/dev/zero` instead. And 80MB probably fits in cache; if so your 'read' isn't actually reading the disk(s).

Comment: `dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/null` returns `2.6 MB/s` why is it the same? and why so slow? okay I will do the same experiment with `/dev/zero`

Comment: please see update

Comment: If you're getting read speeds of 750+MB/s from SATA and USB drives, you're not reading from the disk, you're reading from cache.  If you want to benchmark drive performance, don't use `dd`, use something designed for that task, like http://www.coker.com.au/bonnie++/

Comment: please show output of `cat /proc/mdstat`

Comment: @cas please see updated question

Comment: ok, that confirms it is raid0 and not linear.  btw, do you not care about your data at all?  two raid0 arrays?  it would be much safer to take all four drives and make a raid10 array.

Comment: I do not care as they are being backed up anyway. I am just looking for performance. the other two drives are 2TB each and are much better and faster. The two in question are rubbish ones that I am wanting to make faster.