# why raid0 is slower than single disks

Tags: linux, linux-mint, hard-disk, raid

Here is my raid details:

```
% sudo mdadm --detail --scan
ARRAY /dev/md/blueray-i5:0 metadata=1.2 name=blueray-i5:0 UUID=93a44fb0:9a66b691:f567475e:4a11d39a
% sudo mdadm --detail /dev/md/blueray-i5:0
/dev/md/blueray-i5:0:
           Version : 1.2
     Creation Time : Mon Nov 22 20:03:07 2021
        Raid Level : raid0
        Array Size : 7813769216 (7451.79 GiB 8001.30 GB)
      Raid Devices : 2
     Total Devices : 2
       Persistence : Superblock is persistent

       Update Time : Mon Nov 22 20:03:07 2021
             State : clean
    Active Devices : 2
   Working Devices : 2
    Failed Devices : 0
     Spare Devices : 0

            Layout : -unknown-
        Chunk Size : 512K

Consistency Policy : none

              Name : blueray-i5:0  (local to host blueray-i5)
              UUID : 93a44fb0:9a66b691:f567475e:4a11d39a
            Events : 0

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0       8       17        0      active sync   /dev/sdb1
       1       8       33        1      active sync   /dev/sdc1
```

Here is my disks details:

```
% lsblk
NAME      MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
sda         8:0    0 232.9G  0 disk
├─sda1      8:1    0   512M  0 part  /boot/efi
└─sda2      8:2    0 232.4G  0 part  /run/timeshift/backup
sdb         8:16   0   3.7T  0 disk
└─sdb1      8:17   0   3.7T  0 part
  └─md127   9:127  0   7.3T  0 raid0 /media/blueray/8TBRaid0
sdc         8:32   0   3.7T  0 disk
└─sdc1      8:33   0   3.7T  0 part
  └─md127   9:127  0   7.3T  0 raid0 /media/blueray/8TBRaid0
sdd         8:48   0   7.3T  0 disk
└─sdd1      8:49   0   7.3T  0 part  /media/blueray/WDPurple8TB
sde         8:64   0   5.5T  0 disk
└─sde1      8:65   0   5.5T  0 part  /media/blueray/WDPurple6TB
% sudo hdparm -I /dev/sdb | grep Rotation (Raid0)
    Nominal Media Rotation Rate: 5400
% sudo hdparm -I /dev/sdc | grep Rotation (Raid0)
    Nominal Media Rotation Rate: 5400
% sudo hdparm -I /dev/sdd | grep Rotation (WDPurple8TB)
    Nominal Media Rotation Rate: 7200    
% sudo hdparm -I /dev/sde | grep Rotation (WDPurple6TB)
    Nominal Media Rotation Rate: 5400
```

Here are the benchmarks:

```
% dd if=/dev/zero of=/media/blueray/WDPurple8TB/testfile bs=8192 count=102400 oflag=direct
102400+0 records in
102400+0 records out
838860800 bytes (839 MB, 800 MiB) copied, 6.42835 s, 130 MB/s
% dd if=/media/blueray/WDPurple8TB/testfile of=/dev/null bs=8192 count=102400 iflag=direct
102400+0 records in
102400+0 records out
838860800 bytes (839 MB, 800 MiB) copied, 6.36915 s, 132 MB/s
% dd if=/dev/zero of=/media/blueray/WDPurple6TB/testfile bs=8192 count=102400 oflag=direct
102400+0 records in
102400+0 records out
838860800 bytes (839 MB, 800 MiB) copied, 7.47373 s, 112 MB/s
% dd if=/media/blueray/WDPurple6TB/testfile of=/dev/null bs=8192 count=102400 iflag=direct
102400+0 records in
102400+0 records out
838860800 bytes (839 MB, 800 MiB) copied, 5.56981 s, 151 MB/s    
% dd if=/dev/zero of=/media/blueray/8TBRaid0/testfile bs=8192 count=102400 oflag=direct
102400+0 records in
102400+0 records out
838860800 bytes (839 MB, 800 MiB) copied, 16.0301 s, 52.3 MB/s
% dd if=/media/blueray/8TBRaid0/testfile of=/dev/null bs=8192 count=102400 iflag=direct
102400+0 records in
102400+0 records out
838860800 bytes (839 MB, 800 MiB) copied, 14.5726 s, 57.6 MB/s
```

As you can see, I hava two 4TB 5400RPM disks in raid0.

All 5 HDD are on the same same controller, but this raid0 is performing worse than my 8TB 7200RMP and 6TB 5400RPM disks.

Why is this happening?

**Update 1**

I think the issue has something to do with [caching](https://serverfault.com/a/134143).

Changed the commands a bit and they are giving a little more acceptable answers. Please let me know if they are correct commands or any modifications can be made to make the commands more accurate (given i am not getting any significant performance difference between raid0 and single hdds).

```
% dd if=/dev/zero of=/media/blueray/8TBRaid0/testfile bs=8192 count=102400 conv=fdatasync
102400+0 records in
102400+0 records out
838860800 bytes (839 MB, 800 MiB) copied, 6.51745 s, 129 MB/s
% dd if=/dev/zero of=/media/blueray/WDPurple6TB/testfile bs=8192 count=102400 conv=fdatasync
102400+0 records in
102400+0 records out
838860800 bytes (839 MB, 800 MiB) copied, 6.02803 s, 139 MB/s
% dd if=/dev/zero of=/media/blueray/WDPurple8TB/testfile bs=8192 count=102400 conv=fdatasync
102400+0 records in
102400+0 records out
838860800 bytes (839 MB, 800 MiB) copied, 6.88036 s, 122 MB/s

% dd if=/media/blueray/WDPurple6TB/testfile of=/dev/null bs=8192
102400+0 records in
102400+0 records out
838860800 bytes (839 MB, 800 MiB) copied, 0.199695 s, 4.2 GB/s
% dd if=/media/blueray/WDPurple8TB/testfile of=/dev/null bs=8192
102400+0 records in
102400+0 records out
838860800 bytes (839 MB, 800 MiB) copied, 0.202408 s, 4.1 GB/s
% dd if=/media/blueray/8TBRaid0/testfile of=/dev/null bs=8192
102400+0 records in
102400+0 records out
838860800 bytes (839 MB, 800 MiB) copied, 0.199696 s, 4.2 GB/s
```

Comment: Possibly related - [RAID0 worse that write speeds of hard drives independently](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/281718/100397)

Comment: All 5 HDD are on the same same controller.

Comment: Does it make more sense to compare the RAID0 array performance against each disk in the array (i.e., test each disk, then create the array with those disks, then test the array)?

Comment: Forcing a sync every 8kB is not typical of real-world workloads. Do you get the similar numbers with `head -c 800m; sync` ?

Comment: I vaguely recall striped raid being slower when you deal with a lot of small files (small writes) because the performance is limited to the longest seek time over the raid.  So as Gilles mentions, is it possible that your test is forcing the worst case performance?

Comment: @blueray All drives being on the same controller can be a problem, if the controller isn't designed to handle parallel commands.  I don't know if you bought a controller specifically for the environment or not; but, if this is software RAID0 on a hardware controller, maybe you aren't even using your snazzy controller the way it was meant to be used.

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' can you please give me the full command. I am not understanding how to use `head -c 800m; sync`.

Comment: I have updated the question with caching details.